# JMeter - No Response headers in version 5.1 of while version 3.1 working fine

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Response headers is not getting passed in Sampler Request in 5.1 version of JMeter, while in 3.1 its working fine

I have tried passing different ways of cookies but nothing working

Expected :

```
Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: sessionId=35bb3dcb-6115-1c12-f048-ea8abfb96acd; Path=/
X-avs-sessionId: 35bb3dcb-6115-1c12-f048-ea8abfb96acd
X-avs-transactionId: 9c77afac-f71a-37c3-416a-d1b3cdcff61e
X-avs-platform: PCTV
X-avs-clientIp: 10.60.1.74
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 106
ETag: W/"6a-aQfNSwN1qbr+BJPO+uuBiRAEcD4"
Date: Fri, 31 May 2019 08:54:02 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0,no-cache,no-store,post-check=0,pre-check=0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close
```

Actual : No Response headers are getting passed

Answer (score 0):

This is a [JMeter 5 feature](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html), you should click on `Response Headers` tab under `Response data`

> In View Results Tree, the request and response headers/body are clearly separated to allow you to better inspect requests and responses. You can also search in all those tabs for a particular value

[image]